# babel:octets-to-string throws out INVALID-UTF8-CONTINUATION-BYTE

Tags: utf-8, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, babeljs

I'm writing a lisp program to fetch a web page of a Chinese website, I meet problem about parsing the Chinese words from the binary stream, I already have a vector of (unsigned-byte 8) containing the whole page, but when I put it to the babel:octets-to-string, it throws out an exception.

> (setf buffer (babel:octets-to-string buffer :encoding :utf-8))

The exception is:

> Illegal :UTF-8 character starting at position 437.    [Condition of
>   type BABEL-ENCODINGS:INVALID-UTF8-CONTINUATION-BYTE]

I fount that when it meet a Chinese word it must throw out this exception. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says everything - there is an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in your data.

The most probable cause for this error is that the page text itself is not encoded in UTF-8 but some other encoding for Chinese text. You should check the HTML 'META HTTP-EQUIV' tag and 'Content-Type' HTTP Response Header for encoding.

Comment: Thanks,I checked the encoding and found it just as what you say, the page was encoded in GBK, but how can I process the GBK text, should I write my own decoding method?

Comment: It seems that Babel doesn't support GBK. The best approach would be to add GBK support to Babel. But as an immediate solution, you can use Lisp implementation-provided decoding function. E.g., in SBCL You can use `sb-ext:octets-to-string` function; in Clozure CL You can use `ccl:decode-string-from-octets`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm now writing a patch to make Babel support GBK.